# Как использовать Sha-1 в QCryptographicHash?

Tags: c, qt, qtcreator, библиотеки

Как использовать Sha-1 в QCryptographicHash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вывод уже на свой вкус оформляйте

```
QByteArray data = "my data to hash";
QCryptographicHash  h(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
h.addData(data);
QString res="";
foreach(byte b,h.result())
res+=QString("%1").arg(b,2,16);
qDebug()<<res;
```